# if check box is checked then get product name and price in a array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, laravel-5

If check boxed is checked i want to get service name and its price in array.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKlDr.png)
Image is also given below:
To get values of selected items (i.e service name and it's price in array). Please tell how can I get.

```
$(document).on('click', '.completed_request', function(){
            var completed_request_id = $(this).attr('request_id');
            var prescription = $(this).parent().parent().find('td').eq(2).text();
            console.log((prescription));
            var arr_val = prescription.split(',');
            if(arr_val != null){
                var lihtml =  "";
                arr_val.forEach(val => {
                  //lihtml+='<li>'+val+'</li>';
                  lihtml+='<li><div class="form-check form-check-inline">\n'+
                      '<input class="form-check-input inlineCheckbox1 checkedId"  type="checkbox" value="option1">\n'+
                    '<label class="form-check-label add" for="inlineCheckbox1" id="">'+val+'</label>\n'+
                  '</div>';
                  lihtml+='<input type="text" class="checkedId cal_total checked" id="file_id">\n</li>';
                });
               // console.log(lihtml);
                $("#val_html").html(lihtml);

            }
            bootbox.confirm("Do you want to complete this request?", function (result) {
                if (result == true) {
                    $('#prescription_names').text(prescription);
                    $('#completedModalId #request_id').val(completed_request_id);
                    $('#completedModalId').modal('show');
                     $('#total_amount').val('');
                }

            });
        });
/*
* to selected item names and price
*/
 $(document).on("click", ".checkedId", function() {
            if ($('.checkedId').prop('checked') == true) {
             //console.log($(this).next('label').text());
             var selectedItemsNames = $(this).next('label').text();
             //var row = $('.cal_total').closestval();
             //$('.cal_total').addClass("checked").removeClass("unchecked");
             var checks = [];
             var ss = $('.cal_total').each(function(index, item){
                checks.push( item );

             });
             console.log(row);
             console.log(selectedItemsNames);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where is html code ?

Comment: inside jquery i called html

Comment: You need to get in `json-array` or simple array both values in different array ?

Comment: simple array of both values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever user click on checkbox you can use `each` loop to iterate through all checkboxes which is `checked` and add new values to arrays i.e : `names , prices`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on("click", ".checkedId", function() {
  var prices = [];
  var names = [];
  //loop through lis with checked checkboxes
  $("ul li ").find(".checkedId:checked").each(function(index, item) {
    //get value of price
    prices.push($(this).closest('li').find(".cal_total").val());
    //get value of names and push in array
    names.push($(this).closest('li').find('label').text());
  });

  console.log(prices)
  console.log(names)


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input inlineCheckbox1 checkedId" type="checkbox" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label add" for="inlineCheckbox1" id="">something</label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="checkedId cal_total checked" id="file_id" value="25"></li>
  <li>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input inlineCheckbox1 checkedId" type="checkbox" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label add" for="inlineCheckbox1" id="">something2</label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="checkedId cal_total checked" id="file_id" value="27"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but mam last input value i am notgetting

Comment: which input ? please elaborate ?

Comment: ok mam when i clicked on checked box  i get this ["Amylase"] [""] i.e  getting service  name but price getting empty .One click second check box ["Amylase", "  ASOT Only"]
 ["1", ""] and so on.

Comment: in your html code price is `cal_total` this input ? Also currently your textbox is empty according to your code so first you need to add some value to it then checked checkbox and see if that works . Also , make sure html which i have created in demo code is same or it would be good you can create jsfiddle of your code .